Does Gimp do batch processing?
All previous answers to this question are for much older Ubuntu versions and don't address any updates in GIMP. There is a batch processing plug-in for the Windows and iOS versions called BIMP but apparently this provider doesn't do a Linux version. I don't feel comfortable doing the work on the command line so I'm looking for a gui plug-in.
Ubuntu 22.04.4
GIMP 2.10.30 (which supposedly has a File menu option for batch but it's not on mine)
Is there anything out there?

I don't know if the linux version of gimp has batch processing, and I hope you will find something useful. - However, in the long run, it is really worthwhile to start learning bash and start using the command line for various tasks, for example batch processing of groups of files. I use the tools in the imagemagick package, for example convert for batch processing of pictures. See this link (general) and this link (tutorials

It seems that in newer versions of imagemagick they have replaced convert with magick (I use imagemagick version
8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.5+esm1 in Ubuntu 22.04.x LTS, where the tool is convert.)

I also use the tools in the imagemagick package (for example mogrify) for batch processing of images.

For many kinds of tasks, darktable is a good option for batch editing. Its tools tend to be more "hands-off" with default values, so are more likely to do good job on a batch of images without individual adjustment.

Depending on what you're doing, and how familiar you are with GIMP already, you may find Krita a better (and also free, multiplatform) option for your image manipulation needs.

Since GIMP version 2.2 you can run gimp in batch mode with the -b option and you have a choice between scripting GIMP in Script-Fu (the default) which is a Scheme variant or in Python-Fu which uses a built in Python 2.7.18 at the time of writing (GIMP 2.10.38) interpreter. These are both options for developing scripts in an interactive console that you can later use for batch processing using GIMP, (or writing your own extensions). Both offer access to Procedure Browser from the console:

You can also look at pip installing pgimp on Linux (not Windows) to allow you to develop GIMP Python-Fu scripts from within a python 3.6+ IDE by providing autocompletion for Python Fu - the documentation for pgimp is here.
If you need to do a lot of batch image process I would seriously suggest looking into using either ImageMagick or Python 3 + Pillow both of which give you a serious range of Image manipulation capabilities. It is worth noting that if you have image edits that you need to repeat frequently such as adding watermarks or resizing & uploading either of these may be a better choice than GIMP in terms of both speed & flexibility.

The answer is yes, you can do batch processing, it isn't Photoshop, it's like comparing Dutch with English, there is a bit of learning curve that can be overcome in a week or so, and then there there's never going back to Photoshop once one gets the hang of it. You are definitely not wasting your time!
Let me try to help you.
Option 1:
Open a terminal and execute these commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update

After adding the PPA, install BIMP with:
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry

That should work fine.
If that failed, option 2:
Download and install PhotoGIMP from its official GitHub repository.
Extract and follow the installation instructions provided.
It's working fine here with GIMP 2.10.38 on Ubuntu 22.04
This dude has lots of relevant tutorials and resources that might help you out.
Let me know if I may be some help, I'd be more than glad to.

Note that you generally don't want to add random PPAs to your system that you see in SE answers. Make sure it's safe first.

i'm not sure I understand your comparison of Dutch and English since both languages share a common ancestor that existed ~1800-2500 years ago.

About the comparison, all Scandinavians (like me) speak English and can learn Dutch in days. Hence GIMP isn't Photoshop, but it's easy to learn. I meant to say that it's easy but not equal.
